# Number of neighbours in KNN random subspace classifier

Tags: cross-validation, knn, ensemble-learning, neighbours

I built a classifier model using KNN as learners for an ensemble based on the random subspace method.

I have three predictors, whose dimension is 541 samples, and I develop an optimization procedure to find the best k (number of neighbours).
I chose the k that maximize the AUC of the classifier, whose performance is computed with 10-fold-cross-validation. 
The result for the best k was 269 for each single weak learners (that are 60 as a result of a similar optimization).

Now, my question is: 
Are 269 neighbours too many? I trust the results of the optimization, but I have never used so many neighbours and I am worried about overfitting.

Thank you in advance,
MP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of **k-value** in k-NN is rather **data dependent**. We can argue about more **general characteristics** of smaller or bigger choices of k-values, but specifying a certain number as **good/bad** is not very accurate to tell. Because of this, if your *CV* implementation is correct, you can trust the results and move further with it because the CV will give the **optimal for your specific case**. For more of a general discussion, we can say these about the choice of the **k-value**:

1- **Smaller choice of k-value** : Small choice of k-values might increase the overall accuracy and are less costly to implement, but will make the system less robust to noisy input.

2- **Bigger choice of k-value** : Bigger choice of k-values will make the system more robust against noisy input, but will be more costly to execute and have weaker decision boundaries compared to smaller k-values.

You can always compare these general characteristics while choosing the k-value in your application. However, for choosing the optimal values using an algorithm like *CV* will give you a definite answer.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you so much!                 May I ask you some references about this relationship between number of neighbors and strength of decision boundaries?

Comment: You can have a look at this paper : https://scialert.net/abstract/?doi=jas.2014.171.176  It is concisely explained there.The authors also give different viewpoints about the impacts of k-NN parameters over accuracy

Comment: Thank you again for your help! Best wishes